# replace a current fragment to new one without using replace()

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments

I need to replace a current fragment to new one without using replace().Is it possible?

Also **if i didnt use replace will the functionality mentioned in fragments will work??**

Comment: just remove the old one and add new fragment

Comment: Why can't you use replace?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie actually i am using a view class for animation.only this particular module is done by fragments. in order to use animation view class i need to pass the current fragmnt view.but its not working..only the view is coming no other features in it

Comment: @Akilan actualy iam searching for somthing like layout inflatr.but fragmnt functionality is not coming

Comment: @Akilan i cant remove.bcz i need those when pressing back key

Comment: try getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.your_fragment_container, your_Fragment).addToBackStack("tag").commit();

Comment: @Akilan but still animation not working.it looks as if replace is added

Comment: @Akilan it resolved.Atually i add a new view and inflated the fragment view in it.Previouly what i tried was inflating the fragment view to itself.that is why it doesnt work.Anyway thnks